# Is there a way to find vendor specific usb commands?

Tags: linux, usb, libusb, pyusb

I want to control an 8K monitor with pyusb. I know the c++ api functions from their documentation. But they don't supply the values to send for those commands. Is there a way to find what values or messages correspond to the functions to send with a libusb control transfer? E.g. getting and setting brightness, and connecting and disconnecting the monitor, on a Linux machine (Ubuntu server, while the API only supports versions of Fedora and CentOS).

https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst

https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/dell-up3218k-monitor/docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard procedure to figure out vendor-specific USB commands, because they are defined by the vendor.  If you can get the device software running and working on your computer, then you can use a USB traffic sniffer like [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or a [Beagle](https://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle-usb12/) to look at the traffic it generates and reverse engineer how it works.